# Use of byte[] with spring-rest and springfox

Tags: java, rest, swagger-ui, spring-rest, springfox

I am new to REST API design and I have two questions about the API I am trying to write.

I want to create a service that, giving a PDF file encoding, creates an object in the database.

My current service looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public String create(@RequestBody byte[] pdf)
```

My questions are:

1. Is it "recommended" to use the byte[] with REST APIs ?
   PS: the service will be consumed by web clients as well as toolkits.
2. I tried to use springfox to document my API. the UI tool does not allow me to submit binary data.

I used the following annotation

```
    @ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "pdf", value = "PDF encoding", required = true,
     allowMultiple = true,
     paramType = "body", dataType = "byte")
  })
```

The generated JSON is:

```
{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string","format":"byte"}}
```

However the UI interface displays a textarea for the PDF encoding and submits any content as a string. (For example, if I submit the value "5", the server receives [53]).

Do you have any idea what I am missing at this level ?

-- EDIT --

The PDF is generated in the client side from an HTML form. So it is not a simple form submit.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach to [uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) is to use the `MultipartFile`. So I'd change the signature to something like shown below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE) //<-- NOTE THIS
public String create(@RequestParam("pdf") MultipartFile pdf) //<-- NOTE THIS
```

Secondly, For documentation don't worry about the `@ApiImplicitParams` stuff, just yet. See if the above solution works.

After you've determined its working as expected in swagger-ui. Use `@ApiParam` to document the description etc. `@ApiImplicitParams` is used to document parameters that are as the name suggests `implicit`. So for e.g if your method signature deals with raw types like `HttpServletRequest` and extracts the parameters that are *implicitly* part of the request, thats when you'd use that annotation.

Comment: I didn't use the MultipartFile type because the user will not always upload a file. The PDF will be generated in the client side from an HTML form.